# Windows Policies and "Look in Box" on Windows 7

Tags: windows, group-policy, domain-controller

I am troubleshooting a computer that is running Windows 7 within a domain. The "look in" box on save and open dialogs is missing all but one entry. I'm guessing that someone flipped on a policy setting that disabled the other entries, because I am now noticing that entries such as "Computer" and "C:" are missing from all of the computers affected by the system policies.

Can anyone point me to where such a setting would appear within Windows group policy controls?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're referring to items displayed in the Places Bar. This setting, when configured via GPO, is configured at:

User Configuration|Administrative Templates|Windows Components|Windows Explorer|Common Open File Dialog|Items displayed in Places Bar

You can run RSOP from the local machine (if your user account has the appropriate rights) or you can run Group Policy Results in the Group Policy Management Console (again if your user account has the appropriate rights) to determine if this setting is being configured via GPO.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of those are kept under Policies -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Explorer. Check both the Computer and User policies for that, since they both can restrict.

If you have the ability, doing a Resultant Set of POlicies run from the Group Policy Management Console should let you figure out where they're coming from.